# How to parse ContainersReady with kubectl using jsonpath

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, jsonpath

For reasons I need to parse a certain value from the `kubectl get pods` respsonse.

I need the value of `status.conditions..status` where `status.conditions..type=="ContainersReady"`.

But I'm struggling with the required `jsonpath` query.

I can retrieve the structure as follows:

`-o jsonpath='{range @.status.conditions}{@}{end}{"\n"}' | jq`:

```json
[
  {
    "lastProbeTime": null,
    "lastTransitionTime": "2023-10-02T10:45:42Z",
    "status": "True",
    "type": "Initialized"
  },
  {
    "lastProbeTime": null,
    "lastTransitionTime": "2023-10-02T10:45:46Z",
    "status": "True",
    "type": "Ready"
  },
  {
    "lastProbeTime": null,
    "lastTransitionTime": "2023-10-02T10:45:46Z",
    "status": "True",
    "type": "ContainersReady"
  },
  {
    "lastProbeTime": null,
    "lastTransitionTime": "2023-10-02T10:45:35Z",
    "status": "True",
    "type": "PodScheduled"
  }
]
```

But when I try something like `range .items[?(@.status.conditions..type=="ContainersReady")]`, I don't receive the expected element.

Question: Is is possible to utilize the `jsonpath` option in the intended way and if so, how should the expression look like?